# Error: 10 [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0 at ja

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, vector

```
package basics;

import java.util.*;
public class VectorDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int size = 5;
int incr = 5;
String st[] = {"Spring Roll", "Pizza", "Pasta"};
Vector<String> v1 = new Vector<String>(); //default size = 10
Vector<Integer> v2 = new Vector<Integer>(size); //constructor
Vector<Double> v3 = new Vector<Double>(size, incr); //constructor
v1.add("Hello");
v1.add("My");
v1.add("Dear");
v1.add("friend");
v1.add("shashank");
v1.add("bye");
//System.out.println(v1);
List<String> l1 = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(st)); //we can create Vector using this method.
//System.out.println(l1);
//Default vector
Vector vd = new Vector(); // object creation of Vector class.
vd.add(23);
vd.add("Any string ");
//System.out.println(vd);
//System.out.println(v3.capacity());
v3.add(1.1); v3.add(1.2); v3.add(1.3); v3.add(1.4); v3.add(1.5); v3.add(1.6); //
System.out.println(v3.capacity());
System.out.println(v3);
//v1.get(size);
//v1.lastElement();
//v1.sort(null);
//v1.remove(0);
//v1.clear();

//System.out.println(v1.lastElement());

v3.get(size);
v3.lastElement();
v3.sort(null);
v3.remove(0);
v3.clear();

System.out.println(v3.remove(0));
System.out.println(v3);


}
}
```

I am getting the output as
10
[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]
and error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
at java.base/java.util.Vector.remove(Vector.java:844)
at OOPSisFun/basics.VectorDemo.main(VectorDemo.java:45)

Comment: What else did you expect to happen when calling `v3.remove(0)` in the second-last `println` statement, ***after*** you have called `v3.clear()` in the statement right before it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Vector v3` that is causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` basically this exception is thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index.

---

You have created an instance of the vector that is totally fine

```
Vector<Double> v3 = new Vector<Double>(size, incr); //constructor
```

And you have added some elements there,.

```
 v3.add(1.1); v3.add(1.2); v3.add(1.3); v3.add(1.4); v3.add(1.5); v3.add(1.6); //
```

And you wanted to get the size of the `Vector` and to remove element in index 0 , we are good for now.

```
v3.get(size);
v3.remove(0);
```

### Here comes the problem

With this line `v3.clear()` you have removed all elements in the `Vector` so basically there are no elements in the `Vector` ,so if you try to access an index of element in an empty array it will throw you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` like in your case you tried to access the element in index 0 with  `System.out.println(v3.remove(0));`,but there is no element in this index because the Vector is empty.

---

So if you still want to use clear method use it in the end like this

```
        v3.get(size);
        v3.lastElement();
//       v3.sort(null);
        v3.remove(0);
       
        System.out.println(v3.remove(0));
        System.out.println(v3);

        v3.clear();
```